# Write col names while writing csv files in R

Tags: r

What is the proper way to append col names to the header of csv table which is generated by `write.table` command?
For example `write.table(x, file, col.names= c("ABC","ERF"))` throws error saying `invalid col.names specification`.Is there way to get around the error, while maintaining the function header of `write.table`.

Edit:
I am in the middle of writing large code, so exact data replication is not possible - however, this is what I have done:
`write.table(paste("A","B"), file="AB.csv", col.names=c("A1","B1"))` , I am still getting this error `Error in write.table(paste("A","B"), file="AB.csv", col.names=c("A", : invalid 'col.names' specification.`

Comment: According to the docs, that should work.  Unless you don't have exactly 2 columns. Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @motiur When i use your code there is no problem in writing column names if i have 2 columns in a data

Comment: Please see my edits.

Comment: `paste("A", "B")` returns a single string/column, and you specify two column names.  Hence, the error.

Comment: I want to concatenate two variables - so I thought this would be a good option - should I use c("A","B")

Comment: Is there a solution to the problem - it seems that using character vector is not solving the problem.

Comment: I guess you need `write.table(cbind.data.frame("A","B"), file="AB.csv", col.names=c("A1","B1"))` assuming both A and B are vectors.

Comment: Your example code, where you write

    `write.table(paste("A","B"), file="AB.csv", col.names=c("A1","B1"))`

that gives you an error tries to write ONE character string ("AB") with 2 column names to the file which obviously can not work! What are you trying to accomplish? merge to objects and write the result with the correct column names into a file?

Answer (score 9):

Is that what you expect, tried my end

```
df <- data.frame(condition_1sec=1)

df1 <- data.frame(susp=0)

write.table(c(df,df1),file="table.csv",col.names = c("A","B"),sep = ",",row.names = F)
```